# Limit of an integral related to Gamma function: $ \lim_{k \to \infty}\int_{0}^{k} x^{n}\left(1 - {x \over k}\right)^{k}\,\mathrm{d}x = n! $

Tags: integration, measure-theory, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral, gamma-function

I have the following equality:
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty}\int_{0}^{k}
x^{n}\left(1 - {x \over k}\right)^{k}\,\mathrm{d}x = n!
$$

What I think is that after taking the limit inside the integral ( maybe with the help of Fatou's Lemma, I don't know how should I do that yet ), then get

$$
\int_{0}^{k}\lim_{k \to \infty}\left[\,%
x^{n}\left(1 - {x \over k}\right)^{k}\,\right]\mathrm{d}x =
\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{n}\,\mathrm{e}^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x =
\Gamma\left(n + 1\right) = n!
$$

How can I give a clear proof ?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By writing
$$
\int_{0}^{k} x^{n}\Big(1-\cfrac{x}{k}\Big)^{k}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathbf{1}_{[0,k]}(x)\: x^{n}\Big(1-\cfrac{x}{k}\Big)^{k}dx,
$$ observing that
$$
0\le \mathbf{1}_{[0,k]}(x)\: x^{n}(1-\cfrac{x}{k})^{k}\le x^ne^{-x}, \quad x\ge0,
$$ and, for $x\ge 0$,
$$
\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\Big(1-\cfrac{x}{k}\Big)^{k}=e^{-x}
$$ one may use the [Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem).

Comment: I could never seen the transition using the characteristic function. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Besides the short [$\texttt{@Olivier Oloa}$ answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2005812/85343), another straightforward alternative is based on the *Beta Function* as follows:

\begin{align}
\lim_{k \to \infty}\int_{0}^{k}
x^{n}\pars{1 - {x \over k}}^{k}\,\dd x &
\,\,\,\stackrel{x/k\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\,\,\,
\lim_{k \to \infty}\bracks{k^{n + 1}\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}\pars{1 - x}^{k}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{k \to \infty}\bracks{k^{n + 1}\,\mrm{B}\pars{n + 1,k + 1}}\qquad
\pars{~\mrm{B}:\ Beta\ Function~}
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{k \to \infty}\bracks{k^{n + 1}\,
{\Gamma\pars{n + 1}\Gamma\pars{k + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{k + n + 2}}}\qquad
\pars{~\Gamma:\ Gamma\ Function~}
\\[5mm] & =
n!\,\lim_{k \to \infty}\bracks{k^{n + 1}\,
{k! \over \pars{k + n + 1}!}}
\\[5mm] & =
n!\,\lim_{k \to \infty}
{1 \over \bracks{1 + \pars{n + 1}/k}\bracks{1 + n/k}\ldots\pars{1 + 1/k}} =
\bbx{\ds{n!}}
\end{align}